# Convert date time in utc

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc, birt

i have to convert date in utc from locale date time in birt. 
The only problem is that the date is divide in two numeric data type like '20131012' instead for 'yyyyMMdd' and '223112'instead for 'h24:mi:ss'.

Can anyone help to convert this two data type affected from locale settings, with other two in UTC mode?

thanks for anyone just read this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript Date objects are based on a [UTC time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1). When methods such as `date.toString` are called, the local system settings are used to show a local date and time.

You can use [Date.UTC](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.3) to create a UTC time value, use that to create a date object, then use the date object to get a local (system) equivalent date and time.

e.g.:

```
var utcDate = '20131012';
var utcTime = '223112';


// Get a UTC time value
var timeValue = Date.UTC(utcDate.substring(0,4),
                         utcDate.substring(4,6) - 1, // Months are zero indexed
                         utcDate.substring(6),
                         utcTime.substring(0,2),
                         utcTime.substring(2,4),
                         utcTime.substring(4)
                        ); 

// Convert time value to date object
var date = new Date(timeValue);
```

Comment: thanks. At the end i convert the two data type in only one with Date, then i sum the UTC value of difference with the (UTC_offset + 1/ 24) and then i can manipulate in the viewer the correct value of the date variable.